How to mock single imported variable in vitest for different test cases
I have defined a single constant, who's definition depends on DOM:
// utils.ts
export const isRootPresent = Boolean(document.querySelector('#root'));

My react app uses it do show/hide text:
// App.tsx
import './App.css'
import { isRootPresent } from './utils';

export function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {
        isRootPresent && <h1 data-testid="test-heading">Root is present</h1>
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default App

How do I define test cases for positive and negative scenarios? I've tried to do this:
import {render  , screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import {isRootPresent} from './utils.ts';
import { afterEach } from 'vitest';

const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => {
  return {
    isRootPresent: true,
  }
})

vi.mock('./utils.ts', () => {
  return {
    isRootPresent: mocks.isRootPresent,
  }
})

describe("App component", () => {
  it("should render Root is present text", () => {
    mocks.isRootPresent = true;
    render(<App/>)
    expect(screen.getByTestId('test-heading')).not.toBeNull();
    expect(screen.getByTestId('test-heading').textContent).toBe('Root is present')
  })

  it("should not render Root is present text", () => {
    mocks.isRootPresent = false;
    render(<App/>)
    expect(screen.getByTestId('test-heading')).toBeNull();
  })
})

But the second test is never able to change mocks.isRootPresent to false. It seems to be a common use case for testing tool, but I'm unable to find a solution to it in documentation.

BTW I'm able to refactor my code, so the isRootPresent becomes a function getIsRootPresent.
However I'm not sure if I should update my code so I'm able to test it. Wondering if someone can help with advice to mock a const.

You can return a different value for isRootPresent by changing the way you import the utils module within your test. The idea behind this solution is to mock the getter method (that is called when accessing the isRootPresent property) through the use of spyOn method.
In your case, you could have something like:
import { render, screen, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import * as utils from './utils.ts';
import { describe, it, afterEach } from 'vitest';

describe("App component", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
      cleanup();
  });

  it("should render Root is present text", () => {
    vi.spyOn(utils, 'isRootPresent', 'get').mockReturnValue(true);
    
    render(<App/>)
    expect(screen.queryByText('Root is present')).not.toBeNull();
  })

  it("should not render Root is present text", () => {
    vi.spyOn(utils, 'isRootPresent', 'get').mockReturnValue(false);

    render(<App/>)
    expect(screen.queryByText('Root is present')).toBeNull();
  })
})

Note that I have added/changed some other points for the code to work properly:

I have added a call to the cleanup function in afterEach so that the renders of react testing library are cleaned after each test. If you have globals: true in your vitest.config.js file you don't need that but since you are importing the afterEach method in your code i'm assuming you are not using globals.
I have changed the lookups you were doing by testId attribute to lookups by text. As stated in the testing library documentation you should use queries by testId as a last resort.
I have changed the use of getBy* to queryBy* since getBy* throws an error if the element is not present.

